# Prevent sections of .bash_profile from being run when Ansible connects

Tags: ansible, bash

When I run an Ansible playbook against a server, it opens a new SSH connection and performs the actions. For that purpose I use the same account as for interactive login (nothing strange here, I assume).

For interactive login I added some code to `.bash_profile` to display results of some checks. With Ansible this code gets run on each connection taking unnecessary time (and putting the output my `.bash_profile` in Ansible's results when something fails).

Is there a native way in Ansible to prevent a piece of code from being executed? Like an environment variable I could check against in `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible runs `bash` in a non-interactive shell mode.

From `man bash` (your results may vary...)

*A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.



An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.  PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.*

You can confirm this on your target system via:

```
$ echo "$0"
-bash
```

A solution is to add something like the below snippet/isoloation to your desired login 'rc' files (not only `.bash_profile` - to check what/which files are used varies depending on how your systems are configured)

```
## is the first character a '-'? (as noted in the man page snip above)  
if [[ ${0:0:1} == '-' ]]  
then  
    echo running interactive
else  
    echo running non-interactive
fi  
## nothing after this unless you want it in both interactive and non-interactive sessions
```

---

### Alternative solution

check the value of `$-`:

```
$ echo "$-"  
himBH
```

The `i` here stands for *interactive*.

So you can test `$-` in the following way:

```
if [[ $- =~ i ]]; then
    echo running interactive
fi
```